# How can I add an option to the context menu dynamically in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension in which the client generates some data in the extension and saves it in an array of objects in **`localStorage`** dynamically like:

```
var list = [{},{newly added object}];
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(links));
```

When a client saves some data, I want to show the newly added object in the **context menu** of Chrome. If there are so many objects in an array, it's difficult for me to write this every time:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "****",
    title: "***",
    contexts: ["all"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == "some-id") {
        // do something 
}

});
```

How can I do this? Any helpful suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Not much clear about your question. Say you have an array of objects, and you want to create contextmenu items for every object, so is there any problems with the use of `forEach` loop?

Comment: @Hibara  I placed this **chrome.contextMenus.create** code in background script but it runs only on load , when the user creates new object then background script run only after again on loading and I want to it run just after addition .

Comment: then I guess you should update the question title and it seems a little confusing. I will try posting answer based on my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Every time you call `localStorage.setItem`, you could use something like [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to tell background page it's time to update context menus. Then you could use [`chrome.contextMenus.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create) or [`chrome.contextMenus.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-update) to update the context menu.

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
       chrome.contextMenus.create({
            id: "****",
            title: "***",
            contexts: ["all"]
       });
   });
   ```
2. You could also save user data via [`chrome.storage.local.set`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), which is shared between content scripts and background page, then you could register event handler for [`chrome.storage.onChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#event-onChanged) in backgorund page, and update the context menu inside the handler.

   ```
   chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, areaName) {
       chrome.contextMenus.create({
           id: "****",
           title: "***",
           contexts: ["all"]
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: your option 1 does not create **context menu** immediately after adding new object .

Comment: when i restart chrome then it display .